Laravel BackPack - How to populate select_from_array in update operation
In my setupCreateOperation I am successfully using select_from_array to show a multi-select list
         //Get a list of Roles as IDs
         $roles = $this->getRoles();

        CRUD::field([   // select_from_array
            'name'        => 'roles',
            'label'       => 'Roles',
            'type'        => 'select_from_array',
            'options' => $roles->toArray(),
            'allows_null' => false,
            'allows_multiple' => true,
        ]);

But in the setupUpdateOperation I want to show the current choices as already selected, but I can't see how to do that from the docs. I was expecting something like
        //Get a list of Roles as IDs
        $roles = $this->getRoles();

        //Add an array of roles
        CRUD::field([   // select_from_array
            'name'        => 'roles',
            'label'       => 'Roles',
            'type'        => 'select_from_array',
            'options' => $roles->toArray(),
            'allows_null' => false,
            'selected' => $this->crud->getCurrentEntry()->roles
            'allows_multiple' => true,
        ]);

*I am only trying backpack in my project before I buy to I don't have Pro and therefore don't have relationship fields yet


You need to cast the attribute in your model to store multiple values via select_from_array field.

protected $casts = [
'roles'     => 'array',
];


Do not use field/db_column name as relationship name.

Other than this, you can use select_multiple (relationship) field, which comes under the free CRUD package.
If you need the Roles/Permission module, it is also available as a FREE addon
https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager

Ah brilliant! I thought that relationships was only a pro feature. Thank you!
I had already set up user roles and permissions using the spatie library. Is the PermissionManager better to use in this instance?

Yes Permission Manager wll be good to use. It is using same spatie package under the hood. Bonus: it give UI for it.
